# Exception at converting from string to xml

Tags: xml, teiid

I try to convert from string into xml using teiid server but when I run query this error always appear "java.io.OptionalDataException" ..I don't understand what the wrong.thank you

Iam trying to convert this simple string

```
'<row><id>1</id></row>'
```

into xml using CAST(expression AS xml) or CONVERT(expression, xml)
and mysql query is
SELECT ViewModel.table.column, CAST('1' AS xml) FROM ViewModel.table

Comment: Please edit your post and add a sample of your string/XML.

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky Done

Comment: Your XML is a well-formed XML. So the problem is not there. Please update your post and add your code in its entirety. All of it.

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky create sql transformation at teiid designer ,my sql is SELECT ViewModel.table.column, CAST('<row><id>1</id></row>' AS xml) FROM ViewModel.table

Comment: It seems that MySQL doesn't have native XML data type

Comment: first thanks for your help ... I tried to convert from xml to string and it works , problem at converting from string into xml  @YitzhakKhabinsky .

Answer (score 0):

In Teiid if you want to convert string to an XML construct one needs to use `XMLPARSE' function. Please refer to all XML functions here [1]

[1] http://teiid.github.io/teiid-documents/master/content/reference/r_xml-functions.html

Comment: thanks for your reply... I did that also but same error appear ...any function which return xml type cause the same error

Comment: Then, in that case, you have library mismatch somewhere looks like, how are using the Teiid engine? in WildFly?

Comment: I use teiid engine with jboss EAP server , and use teiid designer at jboss developer studio

Comment: When i create datasource from xml file it works well and create xml table .... but when I use parsexml or any other function returns xml it cause this error ...any help plz?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by created Datasource, the parse function converts to XML type that can be used other XML functions or XMLTable. It needs to be well-formed

Comment: Yes I mean at teeid designer when I create new source by import xml file , it works fine and it create xml view using xml table , but when I try to use any xml function it fails at return this error

Comment: Can you post the whole exception?